# Is this SQL schema fit for storing sports data and statistics?

Tags: mysql, schema, 3nf, third-normal-form

[image]

I am planning on using this SQL schema to store/generate statistics and player data for various sports. I wanted to keep it as agnostic as possible, but given that each sport has different metrics for scoring and gameplay, I had to break it up at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two "red flags" in there:

Any time you name a *table* with the value of what should be a foreign key's value, you have almost certainly got a problem:

- NBAGamePerformance
- NCAABPerformance

These should be merged to `GamePerformance` and a foreign key added to `League`. If there's no such thing as an "assist" in NCAAB (the only difference between the tables), just make it null able.

You should fm do thus because:

- the code behind these two table can be the shared
- if you want to start supporting performance stats for another league, you can without changing your schema (rather than create yer another table)
- you can query overall statistics, or compare statics between leagues easily (possible, but not realistic with split tables)

Remember:

- adding rows is trivial compared to adding columns
- adding columns is trivial compared to adding tables

Design your schema with these principles in mind and your system will be easier to build and maintain.

Comment: So even though other sports will undoubtedly have drastically different columns, just merge them altogether and make each metric nullable? I plan on adding football, tennis, soccer, etc. But the rest looks ok despite what you mentioned?

Comment: How different are they really? You'll end up with "sparse data" (where several columns are used by only a subset of types), but as long as it's not *too* sparse, it'll be OK. If you can abstract the performance data successfully, that would be best. If not, you might need different tables for different game types. Still, the ones you have look pretty similar - surely they can be merged without much pain.